# predict_proba для алгоритма ML k-ближайших соседей (kNN) с LeaveOneOut

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, numpy, scikit-learn, scipy

Есть код с моделью обучения k-ближайших соседей (kNN) по двум группам с добавлением условия: предсказание метки происходит только в том случае, если два ближайших соседа `n_neighbors=2` имеют одинаковую метку. Например, если две метки [1. , 1.], то 1, если [0. , 0.] то 0, при других вариантах - предсказания нет.

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import LeaveOneOut

knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=2, n_jobs=-1, weights='distance').fit(X, Y)
y_knn = knn.predict(x_test)
print('все предсказания', y_knn)

y_knn_filt = np.max(knn.predict_proba(x_test), axis=1) == 1
print('фильтр уверенных предсказаний', y_knn_filt)
print('только уверенные предсказания', np.array(y_knn)[y_knn_filt])
AA = accuracy_score(a[y_test], y_knn)
print('score по всем предсказаниям', AA)
AA_filt = accuracy_score(np.array(y_test)[y_knn_filt], np.array(y_knn)[y_knn_filt])
print('score по уверенным предсказаниям', AA_filt)
```

Подскажите, как можно это условие перенести для модели обучения k-ближайших соседей (kNN) с перекрестным обучением все кроме одного `LeaveOneOut`.
Вот код:

```
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=2, n_jobs=-1, weights='distance').fit(X, Y)
scores = cross_val_score(knn, X, Y, cv=LeaveOneOut())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, что вам нужно.
Метод kneighbors возвращает К ближайших соседей к классифицируемой точке. Причем возвращает как расстояния до них, так и их метки класса. Можно проверить на любое условие до присвоения метки вашей классифицируемой точки.

Comment: Спасибо, почитаю про этот метод. Можете пример кода kneighbors с возвратом меток у ближайших соседей привести?

Comment: Пример есть в документации https://ogrisel.github.io/scikit-learn.org/sklearn-tutorial/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html

Comment: спасибо, изучаю.

Comment: не нашел на этой странице нужный метод. Вернее есть метод kneighbors, как вы говорили, но он возвращает дистанцию и номер выборки, а не дистанцию и метку у ближайших соседей.

Comment: Там же в примере написано " it returns [[0.5]], and [[2]], which means that the element is at distance 0.5 and is the third element of samples (indexes start at 0)". Другими словами он возвращает расстояние и индекс ближайшего элемента в исходной выборке. Имея этот индекс легко найти и метку его класса (из параметра-списока Y метода fit).

Comment: Да, забыл утонить - метода fit объекта KNeighborsClassifier, естественно.

Comment: Да, спасибо. Получилось найти метки класса и проверить их одинаковость. `neigh = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=2).fit(X)
AA = neigh.kneighbors(x_test)
for i in AA[1]:
    if np.unique(Y[i]).size == 1:
        print('da', Y[i])
    else:
        print('net')`, 
но пока это условие просто аналогично приведенному мной в коде `y_knn_filt = np.max(knn.predict_proba(x_test), axis=1) == 1` для обучению и проверки по группам, а как это все сделать именно для перекрестной проверки все кроме одного `LeaveOneOut` (код приведен в вопросе) этого я не пойму. Вы не знаете как это можно сделать?

Comment: Вот более понятно задал вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1096746/362663 Может знаете как можно сделать? или хотя бы в каком направлении копать